# Match corresponding records on different sheets

Tags: excel

For example: I have two sheets, both with matching columns, Column A and B are the same on both sheet. Column A on both sheets will always match, they will always contain the same value, but Column B may be different, like in the example bellow. All of the data matches besides row 3. In Sheet 1 it has "c" in column B, but in Sheet 2 it has "f" in column B.

What I am trying to do is have a column that shows if they match or not, so in the example, row 1, 2 and 4 would all have "match", but row 3 it would say "mismatch" and I am trying to have this all on a separate sheet (sheet 3).

I think Vlookup would be the best bet, but I have no idea where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

**Sheet 1:**

ColumnA | ColumnB

1 | a

2 | b

3 | c

4 | d

**Sheet 2:**

ColumnA |ColumnB

1 | a

2 | b

3 | f

4 | d

**Sheet 3:**

ColumnA |ColumnB

1 | match

2 | match

3 | mismatch

4 | match

Comment: re: *'but I have no idea where to start'* - Start [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two lookup equal each other than match, otherwise no match, In B1 of Sheet3:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE),"Match","Mismatch")
```

And copy down.

Comment: Do the values in A1 have to be in the same order? because for the data I am using they are not. Like: in one sheet, A1 looks like: 1, 2, 3, 4. but in the second sheet it looks like: 2, 3, 1, 4. I keep getting a N/A when I run that formula.

Comment: Then the value is not in one or both of the sheets column A.  Order will not matter.  Only that the value exists in both sheets column A.  Check the  spelling of the sheet names.  Check that the data does not have extra non printable character such as spaces that would cause it to not be the same.  Check that you are not comparing numbers to text that looks like numbers.